# Creating completely new WordPress site from old WP contents

Tags: theme-development, installation

I have an **old WordPress 3.5 site** , but now I'm working in **creating completely a new** WordPress project, it will be using the latest WP 3.8.1 and new design with a theme that i bought.
Kindly, if someone can help me with this points:

- I need to use all the content from the old WP site ( the data itself as a raw martial e.g: if i have 1000 post i need to use them in my new site, i don't need to enter them again instead reuse them).

Taking in consideration that the new website will be different in (categories, tags, new pages, new menu) that's what i mean by completely new, so **i'm not upgrading or migrating**.

I hope that i make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

Your first issue is off topic, but if you use the same permalink structure, and the domain name is unchanged, you should be fine.

The easiest way to use the old content from your site is to do an export from the old site (Tools > Export) and then import into the new one (Tools > Import > WordPress)

Comment: i tried to do this, but the post did't displayed correctly, but thanks for the help